# What is this feature in Linux 'to highlight characters' with QT?

Tags: linux, qt, highlighting

Recently I came across [this](http://qt-project.org/faq/answer/does_qt_for_embedded_linux_support_keyboard_navigation) site.

It says, in Linux with QT, it is possible 'to highlight characters' by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd> {<kbd>Left</kbd>,<kbd>Right</kbd>} or <kbd>Shift</kbd> {<kbd>Left</kbd>,<kbd>Right</kbd>}.

Could somebody please explain this feature with a screenshot or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Behavior**

It is possible that the site is referring to a common behavior of [text boxes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_box) where holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> and hitting the cursor keys moves the cursor and toggles the highlighting of the characters that the cursor moves over. It is also common for holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and hitting the cursor keys to make the cursor jump on word boundaries. Holding down both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> would cause the cursor to highlight text and jump on word boundaries. You can experiment with this behavior in a browser, text editor, or other application that has a text box.

**The Notation**

`{item1,item2}` is somewhat arcane notation for displaying multiple possibilites. <kbd>Shift</kbd>{<kbd>Left</kbd>,<kbd>Right</kbd>} expands to <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Right</kbd>.

**The Framework**

[qt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28framework%29) is a cross-platform application framework that [implements](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/qlineedit.html) several types of text boxes. It is possible that the site was referring to this framework.